# How to make associative array with number as string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have a code :

```
var index = 100;

var arr =[];

arr[index.toString()] = "Hello"
```

The result : index still known as integer not a string. Anyone can explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: array index is  integer, use an object `var arr ={}`

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Actually, the keys of an array are strings, just like any other object.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays". But more importantly, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? It's good to reduce a coding problem to the simplest possible example, but perhaps we've gone too far here. What real-life problem do you want to solve? What are the code's inputs and the desired outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare **associative arrays** using `{}`, which creates  a new `object`, because in JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes.

You need to declare an object: `var arr={};`

- **arrays** use **numbered indexes**.
- **objects** use **named indexes**.

```js
var index = 100;
var arr ={};
arr[index.toString()] = "Hello";
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Nope. Arrays are objects, they can have non-index properties (and in fact, even array indexes are strings).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Arrays are a special kind of objects, with numbered indexes.

Comment: Right. Which are strings. From [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type): "An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2^53-1. An *array index* is an *integer index* whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2^32-1."

Comment: It's one of the more bizarre things about JavaScript. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> How to make associative array with number as string in Javascript

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays in the sense that term is frequently used. It has objects, and as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), it has `Map`s.

> The result : index still known as integer not a string. Anyone can explain what's wrong with my code?

The `index` *variable*'s value is still a number, yes, because you haven't done anything to change it. But the index in the array is a string (and would be even if you didn't use `.toString()`), because standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)<sup>1</sup>, they're objects with special handling of a class of properties (ones whose names are strings that fit the spec's definition of an array index), a special `length` property, and that use `Array.prototype` as their prototype.

Here's proof that array indexes are strings:

```js
var a = [];
a[0] = "zero";
for (var name in a) {
  console.log("name == " + name + ", typeof name == " + typeof name);
}
```

That said, you don't want to use an array when you want a generic object or map.

Here's using a generic object for name/value mappings:

```js
var o = Object.create(null);
var name = "answer";
o[name] = 42;
console.log(o[name]); // 42
```

The property names in objects are strings or (as of ES2015) Symbols. I used `Object.create(null)` to create the object so it wouldn't have `Object.prototype` as its prototype, since that gives us properties (`toString`, `valueOf`, etc.) that we don't want if we're using the object as a map.

Here's using a `Map`:

```js
var m = new Map();
var name = "answer";
m.set(name, 42);
console.log(m.get(name)); // 42
```

The main advantages `Map`s have over objects are:

- Their keys can be anything, not just strings or Symbols
- They're *iterable*, so you can use `for-of` to loop through the mappings they contain
- `Map`s have a `size` property telling you how many entries they have
- `Map`s guarantee that iteration of their entries is performed in the order the entries were added to the map

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which holds any type as key.

```js
var map = new Map;

map.set(100, "Hello");
map.set('100', "Foo");

console.log(map.get(100));   // 'Hello'
console.log(map.get('100')); // 'Foo'
console.log([...map]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes**, in JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes.

**If you use a named index, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.**
After that, all array methods and properties will produce incorrect results.

As you can see in the following example:

```js
var person = [];
person["firstName"] = "John";
person["lastName"] = "Doe";
person["age"] = 46;
var x = person.length;         // person.length will return 0
console.log(x);
var y = person[0];             // person[0] will return undefined
console.log(y);
```

Comment: _If you use a named index, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object. After that, all array methods and properties will produce incorrect results._ No, this isn't how it works at all. An array is also an object, and you can assign values either to numeric indices or named properties, and both will work. An array doesn't switch into "object mode" just because you assigned a value to a named property. Numeric indices  and `.length` work the same after that. Of course if we're talking about _optimization_ the performance may change, but the actual _behavior_ doesn't change.